# How to generate Live Preview Links for Blogger

Tags: jquery, blogger

This is my website - http://www.adityanarayansharma.com

I found that using Jquery Live preview links can be developed but unsure how to implement it all in blogger . Can someone please help me with generating live preview links in my blogger ? Thanks

Comment: use iframes to show your site in one page as below

<iframe src="http://www.adityanarayansharma.com/p/home.html" style="width:100%; height: 100%"></iframe>

Comment: Yes but what code I should add ? I mean I must modify the <a> tags so that on mouse hover an iframe appears with url same as the href. What should be the code and where should I place it ? Can you please tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example. Click on button to preview your blog in popup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button for show popup -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Preview</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe src="adityanarayansharma.com/p/home.html"; style="width:100%; height: 500px"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```